# Make clicked position as center of container

Tags: jquery, html

I implement this code : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/buCLX/)

I want when clicked on the parent div ,  all of child elements width and height growth and the clicked position stand in center of parent div.this is like zoom operation.

This is my Code :

```
 $(".forzoom").click(function (e) {
        var frame = $(this);
        var offset = $(this).offset(); 
        frame.find("div").each(function () {

            var currentItemWidth = $(this).width();
            var currentItemHeight = $(this).height();
            $(this).animate({ 'width': currentItemWidth * 2, 'height': currentItemHeight * 4 }, 400, function () {

                frame.scrollTop((e.clientY - offset.top)*4);

            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: @BradM I want to the clicked position be center of parent container

Comment: Its not perfect, but this way might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/buCLX/8/

Comment: It looks like your demo code (and @hapi's) does what you explain; the inner divs' height and width expands to the height and width of the parent (making them appear centered). What are you having trouble with / could you further explain your previous comment to BradM, maybe with an example of what you mean?

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby For example,when click on the green div,it must be placed in center of the parent by scrollLeft and scrollTop if it's possible ...

Comment: Ohh, so not actually change the width and height, just move them so they are centered horizontally & vertically in the parent.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby No,i want to simulate zoom operation actually